# thumbnails gallery with bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make an thumbnail gallery (2x2) with twitter bootstrap, but I'm not getting the desired effect. in 1st thumbnail of each line, from line 2, is applied to the left margin, making it only fits one image per line.

[image: the problem]

**the code:**

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
        <div class="span6">
            <h2 id="clients">Clients</h2>

            <div class="row-fluid">
                <ul class="thumbnails">
                    <li class="span6">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span6">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span6">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="span6">
                        <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="span6">
            <h2 id="testiominals">Testemunhos</h2>

            <blockquote>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                <small>Someone famous <a href=""><cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></a></small>
            </blockquote>

            <blockquote>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                <small>Someone famous <a href=""><cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></a></small>
            </blockquote>

            <blockquote>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
                <small>Someone famous <a href=""><cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></a></small>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about multiple rows? Code below; [fiddle  here](http://jsfiddle.net/technotarek/79vLv/).

```
<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <h2 id="clients">Clients</h2>

        <!-- First Row of Thumbs -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="span6">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="span6">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- Second Row of Thumbs -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <ul class="thumbnails">
                <li class="span6">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                </li>
                <li class="span6">
                    <a href="#" class="thumbnail"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x100" alt=""></a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span6">
        <h2 id="testiominals">Testemunhos</h2>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
            <small>Someone famous <a href=""><cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></a></small>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
            <small>Someone famous <a href=""><cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></a></small>
        </blockquote>

        <blockquote>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer posuere erat a ante.</p>
            <small>Someone famous <a href=""><cite title="Source Title">Source Title</cite></a></small>
        </blockquote>
    </div>
</div>​
```

Answer (score 5):

A better solution could be giving an inline style to all span6 "style":"margin-left:0px;" which will give you the required output without using multiple rows.

One advantage of using this could be that you dont need to slice your array. Though most of the programming languages handles slicing of arrays easily ( slicing the list of 30 elements to list of 10 of which each would contain a list of 3 ), it would be difficult if you are trying to do something on client side using Javascript.

I tried this approach and worked for me: basically i was trying to write a function in javascript to handle the json data to display as thumbnails.